# Wordpress Ajax Getting Response "Null"

Tags: ajax

I am trying to get ID of post on HOME page .So far my coding is

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');


function ajax_handle_request(){
$postID = $_POST['id'];
if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
}else{
    $post_id = "";
}

global $post;
$post = get_post($postID);

$response = array( 
    'sucess' => true, 
    'post' => $post,
    'id' => $postID , 
);

// generate the response
print json_encode($response);

// IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
exit;
}
```

And My jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('h1.entry-title a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
  data: {'action' : 'ajax_request', 'id': id},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data['post']);
  }
});     

return false;
});
});
```

But I am getting alert Null instead of getting the id of post.

Comment: Please format your codes and content well. For more details check **[`this`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**

Answer (score -1):

You are rendering the json data the wrong way.

Change the `success` to the below:--

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
    // Now you can similarly render the other details like details.success
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help But this still alert "Null"...FYI I am trying this on Home page not single post page.

Comment: check if the ajax request is going right... and check if you are getting the response right... You can use a tool like firebug to do it

Answer (score -1):

First, On Chrome or some other browser you could actually check if you get any data from the server by doing "right click => inspect element => network tab".

If your Ajax function is working you should see a GET request. You are using `POST` type instead try using `GET`.

Once you see a GET request you also should parse the JSON data using `JSON.parse` as you were encoding the data in your php function.